# Unschedulable GPU workload on GKE from node pool

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a GPU intensive workload on demand on GKE Standard, where I have created the appropriate node pool with minimum 0 and maximum 5 nodes. However, when a Job is scheduled on the node pool, GKE presents the following error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                From                Message
  ----     ------             ----               ----                -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling   59s (x2 over 60s)  default-scheduler   0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  58s                cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 node(s) had taint {nvidia.com/gpu: present}, that the pod didn't tolerate, 1 in backoff after failed scale-up
```

I have set up nodeSelector according to the documentation and I have autoscaling enabled, I can confirm it does find the node pool in spite of the error saying "didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector" and tries to scale up the cluster. But then it fails shortly thereafter saying 0/1 nodes are available? Which is completely false, seeing there are 0/5 nodes used in the node pool.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 node(s) had taint {nvidia.com/gpu: present}, that the pod didn't tolerate...`

Try add `tolerations` to your job's pod spec:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ...
    ...
  tolerations:
  - key: nvidia.com/gpu
    value: present
    operator: Exists
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `node(s) didn't match Pod's node` you don’t share the manifest file’s detail, but supposing that he has the lines:

```
nodeSelector: 
nodePool: cluster
```

One option you have is to delete those lines from the YAML file. Or, another option is to add `nodePool: cluster` as a label to all the nodes, and then the pod is going to be scheduled by using the available selector. The following command can be useful for you:

```
kubectl label nodes <your node name> nodePool=cluster
```

Regarding to the `1 node(s) had taint {nvidia.com/gpu: present}, that the pod didn't tolerate` message, you can follow what **@gohm'c** suggested you, or you can use also the following command in order to remove the `taint` from master node, that way you should be able to schedule your pod on that node:

```
kubectl taint nodes  <your node name> node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
kubectl taint nodes  <your node name> node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

You can use the following threads as reference, they have information from real cases, [Error : FailedScheduling : nodes didn't match node selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166842/pod-is-in-pending-stage-error-failedscheduling-nodes-didnt-match-node-sel) and [Node had taints that the pod didn't tolerate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484509/node-had-taints-that-the-pod-didnt-tolerate-error-when-deploying-to-kubernetes).